# Django - Getting values from Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to get post `type value` in my template `.html` from `Model` OUTSIDE loop. I can get value inside loop. 
My Model looks like:
**`models.py`:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    TYPE = ( ("test", "test"), )
    ...
    type = models.CharField(max_length=13, choices=TYPE, default="")
```

**`views.py`:**

```
def post_type(request, type):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(type=type)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_type.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**`.html`:**

```
{% block some_block %}

    {{ posts.type}} # DOES NOT WORK - (Getting QuerySet[] only, but cannot call to {{posts.type}} or, let's say, {{ post.type[0] }} to just get that type.

    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.type }} # This works fine in Loop, cos Im inside set... (I can call even to post.title if defined in Model)
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

```
:(
```

----- Edit: ----
**`{{posts.0.type}}` solves problem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{posts.0.type}}` works as well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens because:
`posts = Post.objects.filter(type=type)` - returnes a `QuerySet`, not an instance of `Post`.
You may try:
`post1 = Post.objects.filter(type=type)[0]` - to get the value of `type` of 1st `Post`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this in the template

```
{{ posts.0.type }}
```